# Change password for Parse.com Android (Front-end check)

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, passwords

I'm trying to produce a password check before submitting my form, but I'm not getting the desired behavior. Basically no matter what the user inputs for either field, it will submit the new password from **mConfirmPasswordField**. What I want to have happen is that if the passwords do not match, hence *if (!(mNewPassword.equals(mConfirmPassword))*, then an alert dialog is displayed and nothing more. Based on the code below, this seems like it should be the case but it simply saves the new password to the user either way. What am I doing wrong here?

```
        mNewPasswordField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newPassword);
        mConfirmPasswordField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newPasswordAgain);

        final String mNewPassword = mNewPasswordField.getText().toString();
        final String mConfirmPassword = mConfirmPasswordField.getText().toString();

        mNewPasswordField.setText(mNewPassword);
        mConfirmPasswordField.setText(mConfirmPassword);

        Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitPasswordChanges);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!(mNewPassword.equals(mConfirmPassword))) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChangePasswordActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Please check that you've entered and confirmed your new password!")
                            .setTitle("Error:")
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();

                } else {

                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                    //Update user
                    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                    user.setPassword(mConfirmPasswordField.getText().toString());

                    user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            LaunchPersonalGalleryIntent();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
```

Comment: You mean that no dialog is ever displayed?

Comment: I just wanted it so that the dialog would appear only when the passwords were different. I guess it thought the password fields contained the same strings because they weren't being updated within the onClick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    final String mNewPassword = mNewPasswordField.getText().toString();
    final String mConfirmPassword = mConfirmPasswordField.getText().toString();
```

This will be executed when the `EditText` are still empty, so `mNewPassword` equals `mConfirmPassword` equals `""`.

The two String should be retrieved within the `onClick`:

```
..
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             final String mNewPassword = mNewPasswordField.getText().toString();
             final String mConfirmPassword = mConfirmPasswordField.getText().toString();

            if (!(mNewPassword.equals(mConfirmPassword))) {
```

..

Answer (score 1):

I believe what's wrong is that you are not updating your fields: you should check for new values right when the user clicks the button, like:

```
   mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mNewPassword = mNewPasswordField.getText().toString();
            mConfirmPassword = mConfirmPasswordField.getText().toString();

            if (!(mNewPassword.equals(mConfirmPassword))) {
                ....
            } else {
                ....
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I should mention for others passing through, that you will also need to include the following fields, along with the password strings, within the onClick method.

```
..
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mNewPasswordField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newPassword);
            mConfirmPasswordField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newPasswordAgain);

            final String mNewPassword = mNewPasswordField.getText().toString();
            final String mConfirmPassword = mConfirmPasswordField.getText().toString();

            mConfirmPasswordField.setText(mConfirmPassword);

            if (!(mNewPassword.equals(mConfirmPassword))) {
            ..
```

Comment: No you don't, as long as the Edittexts are declared final (or global), just like you did with the Strings